# Help understanding "didn't" and "doesn't" with the past tense

Tags: past-tense, british-english, auxiliary-verbs

Which is the correct sentence in the examples below?

1. He **didn't** mentioned anything?
   or He **doesn't** mentioned anything?
2. He didn't **told** me?
   or He didn't **tell** me?  (Since, I believe we should not use two past tenses in the same sentence)

Comment: Normally "requests to correct" are treated as proofreading requests, which are not allowed here on this site. But since you have added the nature of your doubt (" believe we should not use two past tenses in the same sentence") your question should be allowed.

Comment: It helps us write a better answer for you if we understand a bit more why you're asking about these sentences. It's better to explain why you're unsure which of two options is correct than to ask for people to correct the sentences.

Answer (score 2):

When using **did** as an "auxiliary" or "helper" verb to form the past tense, it is used with the bare infinitive of the verb in question, the "lexical" verb.

> He didn't *mention* anything.
>
> He didn't *tell* me.

Here we form the past tense using the lexical verb only, which is a shade more formal:

> He mentioned nothing.
>
> He told me nothing about that.

To form the past tense of some verbs, we add the **-ed** ending to the bare infinitive (mention -> mention*ed*).  With other verbs, the vowel changes (t**e**ll -> t**o**ld).

Comment: Yes. It's nothing to do with whether you can use two past tenses in the same sentence. The auxiliary "do/does/did" **always** takes the bare infinitive of the main verb, not a past form.